# Help in generating glossaries?

Tags: glossaries, latexmk

I have a `glossaries.tex` that is added to my `main.tex` file. The commands are in this order in my `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\input{glossaries.tex}

\IGlossary % at the end. No idea what that does. I used a template of my University

\end{document}
```

I already tried putting this in my `~/.latexmkrc`

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "makeglossaries -q '$_[0]'";
  }
  else {
    system "makeglossaries '$_[0]'";
  };
}

push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';
```

I am also generating them manually with `makeglossaries thesis` and it says the `.gls` `.acr` files and so on are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I already got it. I need to use the glossaries with `\gls`.

I thought they would just be listed automatically.